# Matplotlib - How to plot with coordinates of the nodes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, networkx, vehicle-routing

I am currently solving a vehicle routing problem and i want to visualise my solution base on the scatter plot. However, how do I connect lets say for example Node1 to Node 5?

I want to connect to a particular node base on my solution.

[image]

edit: I have tried using matplotlib as mentioned, but i can't get the coordinates.

[image]

The code is written as stated below.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)

# G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.DiGraph(directed=True)
G.add_edges_from(
    [('0', '3'), ('3', '6'), ('6', '0'), ('0', '5'), ('5', '4'),
     ('4', '0'), ('0', '2'), ('2', '1'), ('1', '0')])

val_map = {'1': 1.0,
           '5': 0.5714285714285714,
           '6': 0.0}

values = [val_map.get(node, 0.25) for node in G.nodes()]

# nx.draw(G, cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet'), node_color = values)
# nx.draw_networkx(G[, pos, arrows, with_labels])

options = {
    'node_color': 'green',
    'node_size': 800,
    'width': 3,
    'arrowstyle': '-|>',
    'arrowsize': 20,
}
nx.draw_networkx(G, arrows=True, **options)

plt.show()
```

Also, the coordinates of the nodes are given as follows from node0-6 respectively:

```
data['locations'] = [(1106, 3368.76),
(97.497, 230.937), (55.514, 2920.53),  
(44.019, 5588.47), (2499.09, 242.61),
(2652.1, 2932.21), (2640.87, 5615.41),]
```

PS. I have another problem with this is that the graph kepts changing whenever I run it. How do I make it fix?

Comment: Why Excel?  You tagged Python, and this would be easy in `matplotlib`.

Comment: Use Python, not Excel!!

Comment: I tried using matplotlib. But how do I add the coordinates of the nodes ??

Comment: What are "the coordinates" in this question? The nodes are not plotted at defined coordinates.

Comment: I have added the coordinates. is the val_map in the code referring to the coordinates that i have to input? how do I input the coordinates? thank you.

Comment: If you want help fixing a networkx code, you should not delete the tag networkx. I have no experience with networkx graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[documentation of draw_networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx)

> ```
> Parameters
> G graph
> A networkx graph
>
> pos dictionary, optional
> A dictionary with nodes as keys and positions as values. If not specified a 
> spring layout positioning will be computed. See
> networkx.drawing.layout for functions that compute node positions.
> ```

You need to specify the `pos` keyword argument in `nx.draw_networkx` to add node positions, if you do not, then a new layout will be generated each time you draw the graph.

pos needs to be a dictionary, with node names as keys, and node coordinates as values.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph(directed=True)
G.add_edges_from(
    [('0', '3'), ('3', '6'), ('6', '0'), ('0', '5'), ('5', '4'),
     ('4', '0'), ('0', '2'), ('2', '1'), ('1', '0')])

val_map = {'1': 1.0,
           '5': 0.5714285714285714,
           '6': 0.0}

values = [val_map.get(node, 0.25) for node in G.nodes()]

options = {
    'node_color': 'green',
    'node_size': 800,
    'width': 3,
    'arrowstyle': '-|>',
    'arrowsize': 20,
}


# creating a variable for the locations, as "data" was undefined
locations = [(1106, 3368.76),
(97.497, 230.937), (55.514, 2920.53),  
(44.019, 5588.47), (2499.09, 242.61),
(2652.1, 2932.21), (2640.87, 5615.41),]

# generating pos dictionary
pos = {str(i):location for i, location in enumerate(locations)}

# drawing graph, with positions included.  
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, arrows=True, **options)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You shouldn't and don't need (at least in my environment) to suppress warnings.

Comment: @Mr.T completely agree. Duplicated that from the OP. It is cleaner without it. Edited.